# Xcode 8 swift 3 load an image from URL and pass it to a segue destination

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I run this code, I get a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION and I don't figure out why:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if (segue.identifier == "tblancSegue"){
            let viewVC = segue.destination as! DetailCoursViewController
            //viewVC.delegate = self
            viewVC.nomDuCours =  self.cours1Lbl.text
            do {
                let myImage = try UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string:self.cours1Image!) as! URL) as Data)
                viewVC.imageCours.image = myImage
            } catch {
                print("foirage")
            }
        }

    }

}
```

It's the let myImage which crashes the application.

Thank you for your time...

Comment: Remember, the `!` operator means "crash here" if the value is `nil`.

Comment: usually that error means you got a `nil`.  By looking at you code, I feel that you probably didn't actually get the image.  you can try to print the fetch image result, see if you get one.

Comment: Why are you needlessly using `NSURL`? Just use `URL`.

Comment: OK, but why ? My url is ok, I checked it

Comment: It could have 2 reasons: 1. The string passed to the `URL` constructor is not a valid url. 2. The image at this url does not exist.

Comment: Split the offending line into 3 lines so you can properly read and debug each value.

Comment: my url is: http://www.boisdelacambre.be/images/terrain_blanc.png when I print it it gives it right (but optional) and when it copy paste it in my browser, my image appears...

Comment: I just tried to split and that's the line: viewVC.imageCours.image = myImage

Comment: I assume `imageCours` is an image view. It is possibly not yet created. You should pass the image only and set it in the `viewDidLoad()` of the destination VC.

Comment: that's it !! Thank you ! I passed the image to a variable and then I passed this variable to the imageView in the viewDidLoad... And it works thank you

Comment: Your question state the error was on the `let myImage...` line. Now in the comments you claim the error is on the `viewVC.imageCours.image...` line. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the following line:

```
viewVC.imageCours.image = myImage
```

if `imageCours` is a UIImageView, then it is possible, that this View is not created yet. You should pass the image only and set it in the `viewDidLoad()` of the destination ViewController.